# Mysql selecting geometry collection

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a column full of longitude and latitude coordinates stored like this

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(-2.1238294 57.1714198))
```

I want to select the entire column and print out only the actual coordinates, how is this achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Read the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_geometryn):

```
--  Gets the 1st value from the GEOMETRY COLLECTION
SELECT AsText(GeometryN(GeomFromText(your_field), 1))
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, however the results returned all look like this 4D�D����q��L@

Comment: Thanks @Neal.  It now returns values like 'POINT(-2.1238294 57.1714198)' Is it possible to return only the numbers or do I have to clean it up with PHP?

Comment: @LucasScholten read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-point.html) to see how to use the `POINT` class

Comment: I'm a real newbie to all this, I can't figure out what to do from that document.  May I have an example?

Comment: I have no idea.. I just got my answer from reading and trying :-)